# Postman query tests : pm expect to equal string like

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm writing tests on Postman queries and I'm wondering if there were wildcards to test for equality on a string?

example :

```
pm.test("projectSheet should includes ", function () {

    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    // jsonData.projectSheet === like "projectFile.pdf"
    pm.expect(jsonData.projectSheet).to.eql("[*wildcard here*]projectFile.pdf");

});
```

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression: `pm.expect(jsonData.projectSheet).to.match(/.*projectFile\.pdf/)`